# Redux: Payload type guess by key of Record

Tags: typescript, redux

Initial code:
[(Full example)](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-2nwwx?file=/index.ts)

`createReducer` function typed params with initial storage and reducer name:

```js
export function createReducer<T extends keyof ActionsPayload, R extends keyof AppState>(
  initialState: AppState[R],
  handlers: Pick<
    Record<T, (state: AppState[R], props: {payload: ActionsPayload[T]}) => AppState[R]>,
    T
  >
) {
  return function reducer(
    state = initialState,
    action: {type: keyof ActionTypes; payload: ActionsPayload[T]}
  ) {
    if (has(handlers, action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action);
    }

    return state;
  };
}
```

Goal:

Create reducer with predefined types of `actions`(Action types) and `payloads` with comparison to return type of `state` like:

```html
export const feedbacks = createReducer<
  | ActionTypes.FETCH_FEEDBACKS
  | ActionTypes.LOADING_FEEDBACKS
  | ActionTypes.CHANGE_FEEDBACKS_ORDER
  | ActionTypes.CHANGE_FEEDBACKS_PAGE,
  'feedbacks'
>(initialState.feedbacks, {
  [ActionTypes.FETCH_FEEDBACKS](state, {payload}) {
    return {
      ...state,
      totalFeedbacks: payload?.pageInfo.totalResultsCount,
      list: payload?.results,
      pageSettings: payload?.pageInfo,
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  //... etc with more actions
```

In full example it's works if give to `createReducer` one type but if you five multiple `ActionTypes` it's compares Record to every payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you are trying to achieve here is done out of the box by [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).  But it's still a good exercise to write things yourself!  You're on the right path but there are a few changes that need to be made to your typings.

`ActionTypes` is an `enum` so the type that describes its members is just `ActionTypes` rather than `keyof ActionTypes`.

Rather than using a generic for the action in the reducer, you want to say that the reducer can take an action which is a union of the all the valid actions.  We can use a mapped type for this.

My first attempt

```
type Action = {
  [K in keyof ActionsPayload]: {
    type: K;
    payload: ActionsPayload[K];
  }
}[keyof ActionsPayload]
```

resolves to

```
type Action = {
    type: ActionTypes.PERMISSION_CHECK;
    payload: undefined;
} | {
    type: ActionTypes.FETCH_FEEDBACKS;
    payload: GetFeedbackListResponse;
} | ...
```

But we don't want those `undefined` properties to be required, so we need an extra step.  We use a conditional to check if the payload if `undefined` is assignable to the payload.  If it is, we make the payload optional.

```
type Action = {
  [K in keyof ActionsPayload]: {
    type: K;
  } & (ActionsPayload[K] extends undefined ? {
    payload?: ActionsPayload[K];
  } : {
    payload: ActionsPayload[K];
  })
}[keyof ActionsPayload]
```

I actually think that the `handlers` can be better typed with a mapped type as well.

```
type Handlers<S> = {
  [K in keyof ActionsPayload]?: (state: S, action: { payload: ActionsPayload[K] }) => S
}
```

This allows us to remove one of the generics from `createReducer`.

```
export function createReducer<
  R extends keyof AppState
>(
  initialState: AppState[R],
  handlers: Handlers<AppState[R]>
)
```

I'm now seeing lots of desirable errors showing us mismatches between expected payload types and the payloads in the `ActionsPayload` map. `PERMISSION_CHECK`, `CHANGE_FEEDBACKS_ORDER` and `CHANGE_FEEDBACKS_PAGE` all have errors.

We have some undesirable implementation errors in the body of the `createReducer` function.  We get `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` on calling `handlers[action.type]` because type guards don't work when the property name is a variable.  So we have to assign `handlers[action.type]` to a variable in order to check it.

Unfortunately our code doesn't understand the the `handler` is the handler for this particular `action`'s type.  Even if we used generics we would still face that problem because `T` could be a union of multiple action types.  So we just `as any` and avoid the issue.

```
export function createReducer<
  R extends keyof AppState
>(
  initialState: AppState[R],
  handlers: Handlers<AppState[R]>
) {
  return function reducer(
    state = initialState,
    action: Action,
  ) {
    const handler = handlers[action.type];
    if (handler) {
      return handler(state, action as any);
    }

    return state;
  };
}
```

[Complete Code](https://tsplay.dev/3NDx8N)